# var does NOT keep it's value across bars

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=4
study("Keep data across bars (var)", overlay=true)

// Variables
var bool canGoShort = true
var bool canGoLong = true
var int myTest = 5

// Functions
f_print(_txt) => t = time + (time - time[1]) * 3, var _lbl = label.new(t, high, _txt, xloc.bar_time, yloc.price, #00000000, label.style_none, color.gray, size.large), label.set_xy(_lbl, t, high + 3 * tr)

// MAIN
if canGoShort
    myTest := myTest + 1

if canGoLong
    myTest := myTest + 1

f_print("myTest=" + tostring(myTest))
```

I'm baffled by this simple script that doesn't seem to work as intended.

I initialize a `var` variable `myTest` with value 5.
Since `canGoShort` and `canGoLong` both are always `true`, I'd expect the value of `myTest` to be incremented by 1, twice on each bar:
Once in the `if canGoShort`, and once in the `if canGoLong`.
Say we have 5000 bars, then I'd expect it to finish at 5 + (5000 * 2) = 10005.

However, when running the script, `myTest=7` is printed?

I'm getting the impression that the declaration `var int myTest = 5` is executed on each bar.
It was my understanding that a variable defined with the keyword `var` keeps its value across all bars, but it doesn't appear to be that way.

The documentation clearly says that it should keep it's value:

- https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_var
  *var is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the variable.*
- https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#techniques
  *Since v4 the var keyword provides a way to initialize variables on the first bar of the dataset only, rather than on every bar the script is run on, as was the case before. This has the very useful
  benefit of automatically taking care of the value’s propagation
  throughout bars*

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calcs are happening as expected. What's wrong there is our `f_print()` function. Apologies for that. The version you picked up doesn't refresh the text. This code has a newer version of `f_print()` that does that.

Note that to inspect values bar by bar, as you would want here, our `plotchar()` trick is more useful, if you also have your Data Window open to inspect the value, as you can inspect each bar's value when you mouse bar to bar. See our answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244746/11806240) for our AHK macro that generates the statement from a variable name, if you have a Windows setup and are interested.

```
//@version=4
study("Keep data across bars (var)", overlay=true)

// Variables
var bool canGoShort = true
var bool canGoLong = true
var int myTest = 5

// Functions
f_print(_txt) => var _lbl = label.new(bar_index, highest(10)[1], _txt, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, #00000000, label.style_none, color.gray, size.large, text.align_left), label.set_xy(_lbl, bar_index, highest(10)[1]), label.set_text(_lbl, _txt)
// MAIN
if canGoShort
    myTest := myTest + 1

if canGoLong
    myTest := myTest + 1

f_print("myTest=" + tostring(myTest, "0.0"))
plotchar(myTest, "myTest", "", location.top)
```

[image]
Again, apologies for the trouble. We updated all the instances of `f_print()` in our FAQ. Note, btw, that we use that version mostly for debugging because it holds on one line. This is the AHK code we use to generate our `f_print()` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> for debugging:

```
^+P:: SendInput f_print(_txt) => var _lbl = label.new(bar_index, highest(10)[1], _txt, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, {#}00000000, label.style_none, color.gray, size.large, text.align_left), label.set_xy(_lbl, bar_index, highest(10)[1]), label.set_text(_lbl, _txt)`nf_print(){Left}
```

In scripts that will be published, we use this version, which is more flexible and more efficient, but can't be compressed to one line because of the `if` statements:

```
// ————— Print a label at end of chart.
f_print(_txt, _y, _color, _offsetLabels) => 
    var label _lbl = na
    _t = int(time + (time - time[1]) * _offsetLabels)
    if barstate.islast
        if na(_lbl)
            // Only create label once.
            _lbl := label.new(_t, _y, _txt, xloc.bar_time, yloc.price, #00000000, label.style_none, color.gray, size.large)
            // Fudge return type of `if` block so compiler doesn't complain (thx midtownsk8rguy for the trick).
            int(na)
        else
            // Rather than delete and recreate the label on every realtime bar update, update the label's information; it's more efficient.
            label.set_xy(_lbl, _t, _y)
            label.set_text(_lbl, _txt)
            label.set_textcolor(_lbl, _color)
            int(na)
```