# How to read in 2 timeframe data of 1 indicator in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script

I cannot find any document in TradingView, can any one help me out this problem:

I have **Trend1** indicator from 3rd-party script, it has Buy and Sell data series:

[image]

And I wanna read **Trend1** data on H1 and M15 timeframe like:

```
//@version=4
study("SupertrendSignal", overlay = true)

trend1_H1 = input(trend_1_result_on_H1, title="Trend1 on H1")
trend1_M15 = input(trend_1_result_on_M15, title="Trend1 on M15")

if (trend1_H1 is buy) and (trend1_M15 is buy)
then plot(1)
else plot(0)
```

But I cannot find any guide to do this.

My big problem is I'm new to Pinescript and:

- I don't know how to get data from SuperTrend custom indicator above
- I don't know how to get H1 and M15 data at the same time from indicator
- Is there anyway to debug the data better than plot it on the chart?, cause I'm familiar with the breakpoint in other languages, I don't know how to see its data structure.

Comment: Welcome to Pine! This is the best place to start your journey: 
 https://www.pinecoders.com/ . For your question, search the Public Library for MTF SuperTrend scripts: https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/search/supertrend%20mtf/

Comment: Many thanks, this helps me resolve first 2 problems

Comment: Oops. Sry missed the last one: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#debugging and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656195/what-is-the-equivalent-of-console-log-in-pine-script

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `security()` function. Here is an example

```
//@version=4
study("Example security 1", overlay=true)
ibm_15 = security("NYSE:IBM", "15", close)
plot(ibm_15)
```